# Pull Request Permission

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have question on ADS GIT Pull request permissions Is there any way to prevent others from being able to change the status your pull request? like being able to publish your draft request, setting the complete status, abandoning etc?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to prevent others from being able to change the status your pull request?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

Now, Azure devops service/server doesn't provide a feature to meet this requirement.

To protect the Pull Request, you could add reviewers for the target branch to prevent set the complete status directly.

On the other hand, we could set creator's target branch or repo contribute permission to **Deny**, you need to add specific user to target Branch security page. This not applied to all the creators all the PRs. Just a specific PR and specific user:

[image]

But none of these settings apply to **abandon**. For this option, you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Hope this helps.